# Material-ui <Autocomplete /> getOptionLabel - passing empty string as value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I am using material-ui autocomplete. I am passing to its property options some array of states. The problem I face is with getOptionLabel:

> ```
> Material-UI: The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for [""].
> ```

I have 2 components. The child one is:

```
const StateSelect = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const handlePick = (e, v) => {
    props.setState(v);
  };
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      className={classes.inputStyle}
      options={states}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => (option ? option.name : "")}
      onChange={handlePick}
      value={props.state}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="State" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

And in the parent one I invoke this child component:

```
 <StateSelect
            state={selectedState}
            setState={(state) => setSelectedState(state)}
          />
```

In the parent one I have the React hook that controls value of the StateSelect:

```
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState([""]);
```

So when I initially pass selectedState as prop to StateSelect it is [''] and I am getting this error message. How could I pass empty value as initial and not to get this error?

I uploaded simple version of my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-field-j2o1p?file=/src/inputStates/input.js

Comment: From what I saw that getOptionLabel function is first called with `[""]` which will return undefined in the ternary. Why is the default state an array instead of an empty string?

Comment: i have this wrong behavior by wrong value option

Answer (score 34):

I got the same error. And, the following worked for me.

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name || ""}
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by just setting values like this.

```
getOptionLabel={(option)=>(option.name?option.name:'')}
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem and I had options as an array of strings. Eg: `["delhi", "new york", "mumbai"]`. I fixed it by adding a check, if the option is a string, if not use an empty string.

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => typeof option === 'string'
                  || option instanceof String ? option : ""}
```

Answer (score 2):

`value={props.state || null}`  this worked for me in material UI version 4

Answer (score 1):

Your default value is an array with an empty string `[""]` which when evaluated in the ternary will return true, thus trying to access the property `option.name` that is undefined. You need either to test for that or initialise the state with an empty string which is a falsy value in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Because the option may be your object or a string. So that it don't have property. Hope this code below can help you.

```
getOptionLabel={ (option: Object | string) => option['name'] || option }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding:

```
getOptionLabel={(option) =>typeof(option) =='number'? String (option) :option}
```

In my case, option is an array of strings and numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case none of answers helped.
I used `(option as Object).toString()`

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => (typeof option === 'string' ? option : (option as Object).toString()}
```

And this error only occures for Autocomplete with `multiple={false}`

MUI 5.13.3

Answer (score 0):

I used null to set value in `useState`:

```js
const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState(null)
```