# The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned object ([object Object]) instead of a string for

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am newbie to ReactJS and currently working with @mui controls, Multiselect Dropdown with autocomplete.

Below is my child component that I am working with and getting the error message.
"index.js:1 Material-UI: The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned object ([object Object]) instead of a string for {"label":"east","value":"east"}."

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Autocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";
import { TextField, Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";
import { CheckBoxOutlineBlank, CheckBox } from "@material-ui/icons";
const Icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlank />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBox />;

export default function MultiSelectDropdown(props) {
  //const savedVal = props.StoredMsgData;
  const [updtVal, setupdtVal] = useState(savedVal);
  //const allDDData = props.dropdownData;
  const mode = props.mode;
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const allDDData = [
     { label: "select all", value: "select all", selected: true },
     { label: "east", value: "east" },
     { label: "east1", value: "east1" },
     { label: "east2", value: "east2" },
     { label: "east3", value: "east3" },
   ];
 
  savedVal =['east1'];
  const onChangeHandler = (e, values) => {
  console.log(values);
  };

  const onChange = (e, values) => {
  console.log(values);
   };

  return (
      <div>
        <Autocomplete
          multiple
          options={allDDData}
          disableCloseOnSelect
          onChange={(e, v) => setupdtVal(v)}
          defaultValue={savedVal}
          getOptionSelected={(option, obj) => option.label === obj.label}   
          renderOption={(option, selected) => {
            if (savedVal.includes(option)) {
              selected = true;
            }
            {
             return (
                  <div>
                    <Checkbox
                      icon={Icon}
                      checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                      checked={selected}
                    />
                    {option}
                  </div>
                );
            }
          }}
        renderInput={(params) => {
           return (
               <TextField
                {...params}
                label={props.type}
                placeholder={props.type}
                variant="outlined"
               />
            );
          }}
          style={{ width: "100%", zIndex: 999 }}
        />
      </div>
    );
}
```

I did my research, put on efforts and unable to crack it. Any help will be appreciated. Please excuse me if this is a beginners mistake.

[How to set default selected items in Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919187/how-to-set-default-selected-items-in-autocomplete)
[Material-ui <Autocomplete /> getOptionLabel - passing empty string as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62933583/material-ui-autocomplete-getoptionlabel-passing-empty-string-as-value)
[Material-ui Autocomplete warning The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61947941/material-ui-autocomplete-warning-the-value-provided-) to-autocomplete-is-invalid
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18514

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`getOptionLabel` is expect to return a function that return a string.

So in your case I think you can try this:
`getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}`